# custom font not working as 'fallback' anymore

Tags: ios, fonts

I recently updated xcode to the newest 5.1.1 which subsequently upgraded ios support to 7.1 (from 7.0).

I have a custom font for some Chinese characters that was working fine before I updated but now it's not working at all!

here's a picture of it working before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8fpK.png

and now from the newest version of the simulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYIW3.png

nothing in my code has changed, the font is packaged into my app, I can get the font to work if I *specifically* tell the app to use it, i.e.:

```
   // cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HanaMinB" size:18.0];
```

but it used to work as a fallback before updating.

my first question is **why**?

secondly, how can I get the app to search for which font will display the character correctly?

edit:
directory: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BxKo.png

copy bundle resources: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMLgp.png

fonts provided by app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPZOn.png

the character I'm trying to display in the images above can be found here:
http://www.zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=280C5

> unicode:280C5

I'm working with **Hanazono fonts** which include HanaMinA and HanaMinB

Comment: can you please post some Chinese character as well? not everybody speaks Chinese here, and it is very hard to copy and paste them from the images...

Comment: Could the font size be the reason? How about try to increase the default font size? If it is not, then please add the screen shot of your PList for the property "Fonts provided by application" and also make sure the font file is there in your project.

Comment: @Ricky it's got nothing to do with font size - I added images of my directory, bundle resources and fonts provided by app up top.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Appearance to create fallback font.

Like this:

```
 [[UILabel appearance] setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HanaMinB" size:18.0]];
```

This create default font for all label in your application.
Or if you need only in tableView:

```
 [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HanaMinB" size:18.0]];
```

Comment: `[[UILabel appearance] setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HanaMinB" size:18.0]];` works...but it changed a lot of my other custom fonts! && is there a way to set it as a fallback **everywhere**? And did something change from 7.0 to 7.1 that it's not working automatically anymore?!

Comment: Yes, it is way to create fallback font everywhere. If you wont to configure, where you need to use it. You can use `+appearanceWhenContainedIn:` and class where it is located. More information about appearance you may read this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010906-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)

Comment: @Antigp it's jacking-up my other custom fonts though